# res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemon

I'm getting this error on validating a form how can I resolve it.

code:

```
  app.post('/',[
check('username','Error occured in Username').trim().isEmail(),
check('password','Error occured in Password').trim().isLength({min:5})
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors.mapped())
        res.send('index',{title: "Create New User", errors: errors.mapped()})
    }
// console.log(req.body.username);
res.render('about',{user: req.body})
})
```

error:

```
  express deprecated res.send(status, body): 
  Use  res.status(status).send(body) instead main.js:78:8
  RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: index
  at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:209:11)
at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:200:8)
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9)
at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:702:5)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
at ServerResponse.json (D:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at app.post (D:\nodejs\main.js:78:8)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
{ username:
 { value: '',
  msg: 'Error occured in Username',
  param: 'username',
  location: 'body' },
 password:
 { value: '',
   msg: 'Error occured in Password',
   param: 'password',
   location: 'body' } }
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: index
at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:209:11)
at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:200:8)
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a res.send() where you intended a res.render()

```
app.post('/',[
    check('username','Error occured in Username').trim().isEmail(),
    check('password','Error occured in Password').trim().isLength({min:5})
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors.mapped())
        res.render('index',{title: "Create New User", errors: errors.mapped()})
    }
    // console.log(req.body.username);
    res.render('about',{user: req.body})
})
```